# HTML form PHP post to email

Tags: php

I'd like to make a form that posts data to my email.

I found the following code and it works fine except I didn't get any email from the form.

Here is the Php File

```
<?php

    // Contact subject
    $name ="$name"; 

    // Details
    $address="$address";
    $id="$id";
    $passport="$passport";
    $issue="$issue";
    $mula="$mula";
    $tamat="$tamat";
    $tel="$tel";
    $select_dd="$select_dd";
    $date="$date";
    $textarea="$textarea";
    $file="$file";



    // Mail of sender
     $email="$email"; 

    // From 
    $header="from: $name <$mail>";

    // Enter your email address

    $to ='rodhiahazzahra@gmail.com';
    $send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

    // Check, if message sent to your email 
    // display message "We've recived your information"
    if($send_contact){
    echo "We've recived your contact information";
    }
    else {
    echo "ERROR";
    }?>
```

Comment: Well, did you define `$subject` and `$message`? You probably get an error on that.

Comment: erm sorry what do you mean.. i just learn 5 hours ago haha

Comment: `mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);`, you only defined `$to` and `$header`. You need to define the other 2 as well. Did you learn 5 hours ago? You mean started learning PHP 5 hours ago?

Comment: Where do you test it? Have you a mailserver in the back? If you use XAMPP or something like this the mail will not be delivered to you.

Comment: You mentioned you were getting the data from a form, yet I don't see any `$_POST` or `$_GET` variables.

Comment: yeah i just learned php 5 hours ago by myself.. i still don't understand alot of it - putvande

Comment: My guess is you haven't learned about method superglobal variables. `$name ="$name";` should probably be `$name = $_POST["name"];` if you're getting it from a form.

Comment: timesplinter - http://minhakimtravels.com/tempahan.html i test on here

Comment: i see thank you Ben Fortune.. i will try redo it again now thank you so much ^^

Comment: Start with echo or print statements so you can see if you're actually getting content into your variables correctly. Once you're sure those are right, you probably will find you have a server configuration issue that prevents mail from being sent.

Answer (score 0):

If i am not mistaken, you need to set the SMTP server before you call mail().

```
ini_set('SMTP','mySMTP.serv');
```

Cheers

Edit:

```
Caution
(Windows only) When PHP is talking to a SMTP server directly, if a full stop is found
on the start of a line, it is removed. To counter-act this, replace these occurrences
with a double dot.

<?php
$text = str_replace("\n.", "\n..", $text);
?>
```

If you just started learning, one of the basic rules is always RTM before you start using a function. here is the link for PHP Mail function https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: put the ini_set in the php file?

Comment: are you on Windows or Linux ?

Comment: im a window user hehe

Answer (score 0):

Where did you try this code? Local or on a Server? Is there sendmail (or similar) installed and properly configured on your server?

Quote from [PHP - Mail Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

> It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination.

You should check your configuration on the server and check the mail logs and you spam-folder.